# Play set folders too small

Tags: storage, dragon-ball-z-ccg

I play the Dragon Ball Super TCG and collect play-sets of every card. these cards are standard size. In the earlier sets I could easily fit this in to one Ultimate Guard Quadrow folder but the sets are getting larger so the cards for the set don't fit into a single folder anymore, leaving me with folders with many empty slots.

In an attempt to clean up my collection I'm hoping to have one folder per set. Are there any products out there that store more than the 480 cards that the Quad Rows do, preferably in the same style. I'm not a huge fan of the binder style with loose pages.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen anything bigger than 480, unfortunately, that wasn't a binder.  Quadrow Collector Albums [like this one](https://ultimateguard.com/en/quadrow-album/quadrow-collector-s-album-xenoskin) are probably your only real shot at more than 480, and of course they're binders.  They can hold 30 pages of quad row, double-sleeved cards (so, 24*30=720 cards), or 36 (single sleeved) or 48 (not sleeved).  Quite a lot.

There are some 3x3 page ones that are bigger from smaller companies, but I have to imagine the quad-row is a big benefit to your particular storage needs.  I guess a 9-card page could hold 2 cards (x4) plus one blank space in the middle or something, and still hold all in one binder (like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072RDGCSV)); that's 720 cards, so if you only used 8 per page you'd get 640 out of it - but not as neat looking as a quad row for sure.

I think the issue is that the thickness of a 480 is about the maximum thickness people are comfortable with - plus probably some construction issues.  That 720 one looks really, really thick to me, uncomfortably so, and I'd worry it may bend the cards more than a smaller one would.

Comment: Thanks for those options, I hadn't seen the collector albums, do you have experience with them? I've always been a little worried about damage that the 3 ring binders could do.

Comment: Not much, I tend to use the 480s myself, but I don’t keep playsets of everything.  They seem like they’re pretty solid though from what I’ve seen.